# Trying to create a Cycle for everyday till the day 186 days from now

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use a for loop to automatically generate a new survey cycle for 2 different IDs everyday for the next 186 days. I am not sure if PL/SQL allows this , but when i run my code below; i get an error that my variable ('X') cannot be used as an assignment target. I need to use the variable 'X' to add to my sysdate to automatically increment my dates by 1 day. Is there a better way to do this? My code / attempt is below:

```
Create or Replace Procedure Cycle AS
BEGIN
declare
    x number;
begin
    x := 0;
    for x in 1..186 loop
        insert into cycle ( form_id, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt,  reporting_month, open_dt, close_dt)
                      values ( 777, sysdate +  x,  null, null, null, null, null,   to_char(sysdate, 'Mon'), trunc(sysdate), trunc(sysdate + 1));
        insert into cycle ( form_id, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt, cycle_Tx, reporting_month, open_dt, close_dt)
                      values ( 776, sysdate +  x,  null, null, null, null, null,   to_char(sysdate, 'Mon'), trunc(sysdate), trunc(sysdate + 1));
        x := x + 1;
      end loop;
    commit;
end;
END Cycle;
    /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove:  x := x + 1; as in for loop it will do it as itself.

```
Create or Replace Procedure Cycle AS
BEGIN
declare
    x number;
begin
    for x in 1..186 loop
        insert into cycle ( form_id, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt,  reporting_month, open_dt, close_dt)
                      values ( 777, sysdate +  x,  null, null, null, null, null,   to_char(sysdate, 'Mon'), trunc(sysdate), trunc(sysdate + 1));
        insert into cycle ( form_id, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt, cycle_Tx, reporting_month, open_dt, close_dt)
                      values ( 776, sysdate +  x,  null, null, null, null, null,   to_char(sysdate, 'Mon'), trunc(sysdate), trunc(sysdate + 1));

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Count: ' || x1);

      end loop;
    commit;
end;
END Cycle;
/
```

Comment: thanks! yeah i toyed with it, used to coding JAVA and realized PLSQL doesnt work that way. thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. please accept my answer if it was usefull @JohnWick

Answer (score 2):

No need of PL/SQL, simply use a `CONNECT BY LEVEL` and pure SQL `INSERT`. Your block would actually lead to too many context switches.

```
INSERT INTO CYCLE
            (form_id,
             create_dt,
             create_user_id,
             modify_dt,
             modify_user_id,
             effective_dt,
             inactive_dt,
             reporting_month,
             open_dt,
             close_dt)
SELECT 777,
       SYSDATE + LEVEL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Mon'),
       TRUNC(SYSDATE),
       TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1)
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 186;

INSERT INTO CYCLE
            (form_id,
             create_dt,
             create_user_id,
             modify_dt,
             modify_user_id,
             effective_dt,
             inactive_dt,
             reporting_month,
             open_dt,
             close_dt)
SELECT 776,
       SYSDATE + LEVEL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Mon'),
       TRUNC(SYSDATE),
       TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1)
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 186;

COMMIT;
```